# php htmlspecialchars and not working

Tags: php, html

I have this simple code :

```
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
$html_file=fread($handle,filesize($file));
fclose($handle);

echo htmlspecialchars($html_file);
```

and the second problem`htmlspecialchars`, 
it working correctly if the file in English but when the file have Hebrew text it don't echo anything and don't give me any errors

when I `echo $html_file` it working ok, so the problem only when I use `htmlspecialchars()` does anyone have any Idea why this happen ?

Comment: You have a leading `$` before your function call. That's the reason of the error.

Comment: thanks, it fixed it :) but do you have any Idea what wrong with `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: What is the encoding of your php file? You need to be aware of it as I doubt if Hebrew text is even included in utf8

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy  I use `mb_detect_encoding($html_file);` and it show me that it's UTF-8 but I believe that output of HEBREW text is in windows-1255
the Hebrew text file have English characters too, but it output nothing if I have any Hebrew characters in it.

Comment: No, I mean the encoding of php file, not the html file you are seeking. It can be detected in the text editor

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy
I checked and it show me ANSI, converted the file to utf-8 and now htmlspecialchars working :)
thank you very much :)